# Mini cart doesn't work only after refreshing the page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

My mini cart stopped working. He did it before, just now when I several times refresh the page. Please help me this is my system log:

```
2015-04-24T10:16:54+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 153
2015-04-24T10:17:02+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 153
2015-04-24T10:17:10+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 153
2015-04-24T13:09:05+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(/home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/media/css/b91898aef24311cbad9dcc27ccf869cd.css): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 753
2015-04-24T13:09:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(/home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/media/css/11124eecaaf7442049816083a1320618.css): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 753
2015-04-24T13:09:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(/home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/media/css/d311dcf8966776978064ca4b124dacdc.css): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 753
2015-04-24T13:09:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(/home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/media/js/a2353b9fbd2fa59432acb742a909e6b1.js): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 753
2015-04-24T13:09:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(/home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/media/css/031e031e6adb09429a4642bf1bfa3f3d.css): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 753
2015-04-24T13:09:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: file_put_contents(/home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/media/js/004d73a3559f263ef03e79fcfdbcf4b8.js): failed to open stream: Permission denied  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php on line 753
2015-04-24T13:10:43+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: unsigned  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Helper/Abstract.php on line 310
2015-04-24T13:11:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Division by zero  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml on line 10
2015-04-24T13:11:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Division by zero  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml on line 10
2015-04-24T13:11:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Division by zero  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml on line 10
2015-04-24T13:43:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _prev_prod  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/Porto/Helper/Data.php on line 133
2015-04-24T13:43:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _next_prod  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/Porto/Helper/Data.php on line 171
2015-04-24T15:17:43+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _prev_prod  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/Porto/Helper/Data.php on line 133
2015-04-24T15:17:43+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _next_prod  in /home/mutinct/domains/proward.nl/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/Porto/Helper/Data.php on line 171
```

Comment: Are you afraid about errors in log or you have some problems with your cart? I see that cart on site proward.nl is working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various issues in the log:

- Guess one: You are using DirectAdmin.
- Guess two: You are using an apache module that switches user ID, like [mod_ruid2](https://github.com/mind04/mod-ruid2) or [suexec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_suexec.html).
- Guess three: you have enabled css and js merging
- Guess four: your media directory or parts thereof are not writable by the user 'mutinct'.

Fix that and get rid of the "failed to open stream: Permission denied" messages.

The issue with your mini-cart is the division by zero. Since this is a custom design package (aka theme) you should show the code and some context for `app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml` around line 10.

Your theme obviously hasn't been developed with Magento Developer Mode turned on (as it would break instantly) and using code like this will quickly fill your system log and has the potential to create subtle and hard to track down bugs. The contents of the error messages shows a structural lack of input validation, which can also lead to security issues.

Comment: Quite right about this one... Urggg... dont you just hate it when third party modules throw errors like this. Also to add to this check your file permissions are set correctly: find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; chmod -R o+w media;